# Moving away sprite to another in sfml

Tags: rotation, sfml, move

I just want to know if there is a solution to make my sprite change the rotation in the other sense and move away from another sprite (it position is in the center of the hud view).

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not provide any code or context I can't really help you but to rotate a sprite, use the rotate method of the Sprite class I guess.

```cpp
sf::Sprite sprite;
sprite.rotate(45.f); //To rotate a sprite by 45°
```

Comment: With this code if I want my character not to fix at 45 degrees but to 225 should i do set rotation(getRotation + 180)

Comment: Yes, you can just make it turn away by getting its actual rotation and adding 180 to it. `sprite.rotate(sprite.getRotation()+180)`